# Word/Phrase for a laughter-like reaction

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to find a word or phrase for a particular type of reaction similar to a laugh. The reaction is hard for me to describe, but an example of it can be found in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPY4yOmNw7w). The reaction is actually before the list begins, around the 0:08 second mark.

The reaction I'm after is sharper and quicker than the one in the video: a short, semi-sharp breath out through the nose, usually accompanied by a very slight nod of the head. It's not a true laugh, but does show amusement/appreciation.

> "They're not that bad. Once you get over their endless search for assassination plots, they're a good group to hang out with."
>
> Dave grinned. "You have my condolences," he said, ____-ing. `(meant to show light sarcasm)`

Most of the synonyms for laughter suggest loud or prolonged sounds, neither of which fits the reaction I want. One word which comes close is snort, but that suggests something a lot louder and less controlled than I want. The closest I have come to a description is:

> He suppressed a laugh.

Still not quite what I want, since the character isn't really *suppressing* anything.

**What is a good word/phrase for this reaction?** I'm after a word to describe the reaction to something which is only mildly funny or perhaps sarcastic, and does not induce full laughter.

Comment: I'd be willing to classify the reaction in that video as a *snicker*, or perhaps a *chuckle*.  Also you could get around your writing issue by using *grin* as Dave's speaking action and giving him a different reaction:  "Dave raised an eyebrow.  'You have my condolences,' he grinned." (or 'he said, grinning', or 'he said, with a grin.')

Comment: Immediately the word "snort" came to mind, as @wendyG said below.  Also, the word "sniff" as in "he sniffed in disdain at the joke's weak punchline".

Comment: @Hellion *Snicker* has unique connotations, usually implying snickering at *someone* (usually behind their back). *Chuckle* implies something much longer than I want. This is a short reaction. The grin advice is a good patch for the problem though, if there's no other way to describe the reaction.

Comment: 'Smirk' is the closest I can think of, though it doesn't necessarily include exhaling through the nose.

Answer (score 2):

I first thought of snorting

> **snort**
>
> NOUN
>
> 1 An explosive sound made by the sudden forcing of breath
> through one's nose, used to express indignation, derision, or
> incredulity.
>
> ‘he gave a snort of disgust’
> https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/snort

I know this doesn't look good on paper but you can also snort with laughter

> to make an explosive sound by forcing air quickly up or down the
> nose:
>
> He did an impression of a horse snorting.
>
> Camille snorts when she
> laughs.
>
> informal By this time I was snorting with laughter (= laughing
> a lot and loudly).

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snort

Comment: But I specifically said that snort would not work in the question.

Comment: Fair point, well made

Answer (score 1):

A chuckle or smirk might be what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

a **chortle**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/chortle)

> A snorting, joyful laugh or chuckle.

As in:

> You have my condolences," he said, chortling.